# Pandas, drop duplicate rows, keep those with shortest string length

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame called df:

```
Name     Symbol   
Downer   NEE
Downer   NEE AX O
Downer   NEE.O
Next In  EXC
Next In  EXCA
Next In  EXC AZ
..
```

Basically I want to do this thing when if there is a duplicate in `Name`, I want to choose the shorter symbol length and drop the rest.

So I want the output to look like this:

```
Name     Symbol   
Downer   NEE
Next In  EXC
...
```

I tried to use `drop_duplicates` but it only lets me select first or last. How do I select rows based on this condition of string length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need `str.len` and `sort_values`

we will drop duplicates based on `Name` keeping the first instance (smallest len)

```
df1 = (
    df.assign(count=(df["Symbol"].str.len()))
    .sort_values("count")
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["Name"], keep="first")
).drop('count',axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df1)
      Name Symbol  
0   Downer    NEE      
3  Next In    EXC
```

another method would be to use `groupby.min()`

```
df1 = df.assign(count=(df["Symbol"].str.len())).groupby('Name').min()\
               .drop('count',axis=1)

print(df1)


        Symbol  
Name                 
Downer     NEE      
Next In    EXC
```

or the most simple solution proposed by Jezrael

```
df.loc[df["Symbol"].str.len().groupby(df['Name']).idxmin()]
```

Comment: parentheses should be used at the end of `idxmin`  (`idxmin()`) to avoid this error in the last solution: TypeError: idxmin() got multiple values ​​for argument 'axis'

Comment: @Clegane thanks - feel free to edit next time :)